# Adding Paypal page_style tag in Prestashop

Tags: php, paypal, prestashop

I have run into a problem and was hoping someone with more knowledge on Prestashop 1.5 and the paypal module can help.

I know I can set the default page style in Paypal itself but I have multiple websites with their own page_styles so this is not an option :(

In the Prestashop Paypal module (v3.4.4) I have edited the file:

/public_html/themes/{{theme}}/modules/paypal/express_checkout_payment.tpl

to include the following tag in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="mystyle" />
```

The template is used and the tag is added to the page however this does not seem to work, it is just ignored which means the default style is loaded instead.

Is there any way to achieve this and explicitly tell prestashop to use my given page_style (ideally without hacking core module php files, although all solutions are welcome)?

Thank you for reading and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange but the internet and Paypal resources are littered with suggestions to use the tag name **page_style** (which works great on the non Prestashop websites I have tried) but for some reason on Prestashop it does not work.

That said use the following instead does!!

```
<input type="hidden" name="pagestyle" value="mystyle" />
```

This worked for me both when using the tag in a template or when adding it directly to the process.php file where I put:

```
$fields['PAGESTYLE'] = 'mystyle';
```

I would not suggest the 2nd method as that will be overwritten on a module update though.

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

A note 8 months later with PayPal module v3.6. This no longer works it seems. No matter what template file is modified - BTW the correct one for Paypal Express is modules/paypal/views/templates/hook/express_checkout_payment.tpl. The tag does show up in the form but is not relayed to the API.

So as of today I think the only solution is to modify modules/paypal/express_checkout/process.php as with 2nd method above (Yes, without the underscore).